# Streamline Active Directory account creation via automated web site

Tags: active-directory, password, user-accounts, accounts

In my company we have high employee turnover, and hence our helpdesk receives about a dozen requests per week for new Active Directory accounts.  Currently, we receive these requests simply via e-mail or voice-mail, and rarely do we have all of the information necessary to create the account.  I would like to find a web application that can be used by a manager or supervisor to formalize the requests they make for AD accounts for new employees under their command.  Ideally, the application would prompt for all of necessary information, and allow the helpdesk to review the requests and approve or deny each one.  If approved, the application would take care of creating the account and send an e-mail to the manager.

I have found several application on the Internet that handle self-service account management (i.e., password resets or update contact info), which is also nice to have, but nothing that streamlines the new account request and creation part.  Can anyone make suggestions on such an application?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using standard web forms (php, javascript, cgi, etc.) you can do web forms that make certain fields mandatory as well as validate input.  Any number of languages and APIs would allow you to create accounts if you wanted to be that ambitions.

This if a fairly simple web application that any reasonably-competent webdev should be able to produce for you.  However, I don't know of any products that do what you ask.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was hoping to do minimal, if any, custom development, but that doesn't look promising at this time.

Answer (score 0):

Using Infopath, you ought to be able to make a form that would require all fields, and also generate a script or scripts to do the creation. The script could be BAT and use dsadd, ldifde, csvde, or your scripting language of choice.

Comment: Thanks for your input.  We don't use Infopath, but the dsadd utility may prove to be helpful if we ultimately do write our own app.

Comment: We use InfoPath on SharePoint, but as @gWaldo said, any web scripting language can do what you're asking for. If you have a ticketing system, you could even have the page send email or do whatever it takes to open a ticket, and attach the creation script(s) to it.